# How to edit Woocommerce Recent Products Shortcode so that it only show products published in the last 15 days?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I'd like to edit the WooCommerce Recent Products Shortcode so that it limits the query to products published in the last 15 days. I'm not sure how to do that. Here is the code for the shortcode:

```
/**
 * Recent Products shortcode
 *
 * @param array $atts
 * @return string
 */
public static function recent_products( $atts ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'per_page'  => '12',
        'columns'   => '4',
        'orderby'   => 'date',
        'order'     => 'desc'
    ), $atts );

    $meta_query = WC()->query->get_meta_query();

    $args = array(
        'post_type'             => 'product',
        'post_status'           => 'publish',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
        'posts_per_page'        => $atts['per_page'],
        'orderby'               => $atts['orderby'],
        'order'                 => $atts['order'],
        'meta_query'            => $meta_query
    );

    ob_start();

    $products = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $args, $atts ) );

    $columns = absint( $atts['columns'] );
    $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $columns;

    if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

    <?php endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
}
```

I am thinking that I need to somehow retrieve the publish date for the posts in the loop, put that in a variable, and add something to the while that checks to see if that variable is less than 15 days old? These steps are out of my ability.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Best not to modify the WooCommerce shortcode directly in core. You will need to remove their shortcode and add your own. Or now that I look a little closer, I see they have already provided the `woocommerce_shortcode_products_query` filter for modifying the query args.

```
$products = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $args, $atts ) );
```

Next you need some [date parameters for `WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters)

When you filter the `woocommerce_shortcode_product_query` args you can set the `date_query` parameters for `WP_Query`.

```
function so_31541643_recent_products_shortcode_args( $args, $atts ){

    $args['date_query'] = array(
        array(
            'after'     => '15 days ago',
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    );

    return $args;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'so_31541643_recent_products_shortcode_args', 10, 2 );
```

Totally untested, do not use in production until you test.

Comment: HI - I'm sorry for being slow to review this, I was on a vacation. I added this to functions.php and it works perfectly! Thanks so much! Excelent code and explanation.

Comment: @WilliamAlexander which functions.php file did you add this to? To the main site's or to the theme's?

Comment: @davidrayowens Always your theme's `functions.php`.

Comment: can i use this technique in plugin?

Comment: @WaseelAhmadMufti Yes you could wrap this up as a plugin instead.

Comment: @helgatheviking Thank you for your reply. If I want to change the working of showing related products query? is it works?

Comment: @WaseelAhmadMufti The date query params will work anywhere you are setting up a WordPress style query. But `woocommerce_shortcode_products_query` would not be the correct filter for the related products since that's specific to the shortcode.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) your answer is quite helpful for me